# How to get the value of nested JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery in my current project, I basically want to dynamically create an image for each image src in the JSON array, here's the HTML data-* JSON array:

```
<div class="" data-slides='{
    "imgs" : [{
    "img" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "img" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "img" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
}]}'>
```

I guess there is some 'for img in imgs' logic needed, I've just never dealt with it before. How could I, say 'alert' the contents of the 'imgs' array one by one? :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, currently it is just a string. Your formatting is "wrong" btw- you are mixing arrays and objects (wrong unless you want an array of objects inside an object -> 3-dimensional).

I recommend using:

```
<div class="" data-slides='{
    "imgs" : {
    "img1" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "img2" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "img3" : "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"
}}'>
```

or:

```
<div class="" data-slides='{
    "imgs" : [
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"
]}'>
```

Lets say you extracted the content to a var:

```
var slides = $('div').data('slides'); // or use id instead of div
```

<strike>slides = JSON.parse(slides);  //parse the JSON-string into an object</strike>

Now you can access them by (first way):

```
var key;
for(key in slides.imgs)
    alert(slides.imgs[key]);
```

or by the array way:

```
for(var i = 0, img; img = slides.imgs[i]; i++)
    alert(img);
```

or by the third way (as a separate solution):

```
alert($('div').data('slides').imgs.img1);
```

The latter require a object-in-object for it to work (as the 1. recommendation).

Based on the fiddle, here's a modification showing one way:
http://jsfiddle.net/Evcwx/1/

(if a simple array is all you need you can just put in a pure array there instead of using imgs first - the jQuery check for { or [ and will parse it for you automatically).

Comment: Thanks Ken! How can I simply 'alert' the value of each image, that's what I am stuck on! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ken, great stuff. I am using jQuery however if that's easier! Is 'getDataSlides' necessary, and what does it do?

Comment: Here is where I am at so far if you could help point me in the right direction :) http://jsfiddle.net/Evcwx/

Comment: Does the `.data()` method automatically parse JSON?

Comment: @Halcyon21 I updated the fiddle (see link in answer). The data seem to be parsed automatically using jquery.

Comment: @Bergi, `.data()` does do automatic type conversion, so if it can be successfully parsed into JSON, it'll return the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @Ken that you should use a better JSON structure. If you are using jQuery, you can directly use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get a parsed object. Quoting from the docs:

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

So I've created a small fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/BcR4Y/), which basically uses [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) as follows:

```
var slides = $("#slider").data("slides");
```

Comment: Yep, my bad on that one I am new to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use valid JSON in your attribute. It looks like you meant to use:

```
<div class="" data-slides='{
    "imgs" : [
        {"img": "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"},
        {"img": "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"},
        {"img": "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"}
    ]
}'>
```

Which could be accessed using:

```
var slides = $('[data-slides]').data('slides');
```

The [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data) will automatically convert JSON values into objects if they can be successfully parsed as objects, so to iterate over the collection you could use:

```
var index;
for (index in slides.imgs) {
    alert(slides[index].img);
}
```

Or for the "jQuery way" of iterating over a collection (using [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)):

```
$.each(slides.imgs, function () {
    alert(this.img);
});
```

That all said, the original structure is very verbose, it really could be simplified to a single array:

```
<div class="" data-slides='[
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300",
    "//placekitten.com/g/200/300"
]'>
```

Which would be iterated over as:

```
var slides = $('[data-slides]').data('slides');
$.each(slides, function () {
    alert(this);
});
```